What is this copper object and why might it be sticking out the rear wall of my house?
I'm close to purchasing a small terrace house in the South of England, and during my visit I noticed this object shown in the photo attached that has been cemented into a hole in the rear wall of the house.
The object is copper and appears to resemble a door knob but it's of a different shape so I don't think it is.
I'd like to understand what this object is which could help me understand why it's been cemented into a hole in the wall.
My only thought is that it could be to attach one end of a clothes line in the garden.


How high is it from the ground?  The handle of the pole thing suggests about 8 feet, so an anchor for something is a decent guess.  Your general location might help also.

@crip659 I'd put it at more like 5 feet. Post mentions the South of England.

I'd say it's at about shoulder height — about 5 feet. I'm hoping it is just an anchor for something in the garden and nothing more sinister! The house is in Petersfield, Hampshire, UK.

Copper! Apologies! I would have to return to the property to see if I could move it. Would it be safe to do so?
Ah HVAC! So the property did have a warm air heating system with air ducts that are still in each room (I'm not sure the right name for this system) but this has been replaced with radiators and a combi boiler.

If it's easily removable it should be safe (unless you're buying an old Ghostbusters facility). If it's soldered that's a different story.

Looks like it admits or releases air or water in special situations, IE pressure relief, backflow prevention, overflow, etc etc.   What's on the other side of the wall?  It could also be a capped spigot.   Take the picture to a local plumbing supply.

might be an anti-siphon valve

It looks like plumbing copper (15mm outside diameter pipe but it doesn't look like you can get at any pipe to measure with the thing in the end). It's clearly not original because of the way the wall is patched round it with mortar, but the mortar and even the brickwork look quite new (or well looked after at least).
I would expect it to be either:

An overflow for a toilet cistern or water header tank (the latter is unlikely at this height, the former not impossible) but those are normally plumbed in plastic these days.
A pressure relief pipe or condensate drain for a boiler.  It's a likely height for that.

I've found something very similar looking, a pipe cowl for pressure relief (vent) pipes.
So I'd expect your boiler or some of its related pipework to be on the other side of that wall

Thank you Chris H. Indeed the combi boiler is on the other side of the wall. It definitely looks like a pipe cowl and if it had been installed flush in the wall I wouldn't object to it!

@Jono if it had been installed properly, going by the manufacturer's photos!
